# Describe the points $(x,y) \in \mathbb {R}^2$ such that $x^2=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know this is a simple question that I should know the answer to, but I began second guessing my answer to my question, so I need enlightenment.

Let $y\in \mathbb {R} $ and let $x^2=2$. I want to describe the set whose points satisfy the given restriction. At first, I perceived this set to have a geometric representation of a parabola. But then I thought about how the only two values for $x $ satisfying the given equation are $-\sqrt {2} $ and $\sqrt {2} $. Because $y $ is arbitrary, we then have two parallel and vertical lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: You got it exactly! We have a degenerated conic, which is formed by two parallel vertical lines.

Comment: A parabola wouls be "$y=x^2$" or "$y^2=x$"

Comment: You're right. There is only a restriction on $x$, hence if the restriction on $x$ holds, then any $y$ will satisfy.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I'm guessing wolfram "misunderstood" the expression $x^2=0$ as a parabola.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right because the equation $x^2=2$ can be factorized as $(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2}$) and any factorable  second degree equation represents a [degenerate conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic) that, in the real plane, can be  can be a couple of line (parallel or not), a single line or a single point.